# Chrome uses different (old) IP for https:// than for http:// (new)

Tags: ssl, https, dns, google-chrome-devtools, chromium

This makes no sense to me.

I am migrating a website with a couple of domains to a new host.  The DNS changes have been made and seem to have fully propagated.  Certainly my local machine and a couple of remote tests all see the new IP address.

Using Chromium

- Dev Tools Network Tab open, Remote Address column visible
- Version 57.0.2987.98 Built on 8.7, running on Debian 8.9 (64-bit)

If I go to http://private.tibit.com everything is fine.  The first request:

`private.tibit.com  200  http  77.104.180.216:80  document  Other   936 B   23 ms`

But if I go to https://private.tibit.com, the first request is going to the old IP Address, the first request is:

`private.tibit.com  200 https  185.119.173.19:443  document  Other  (from ServiceWorker)  10 ms`

How can this be?  Curl http:// or https:// from my console both go to the new address.  Firefox goes to the new address. I just checked and even an Incognito Tab goes to the new address.

I have tried disabling all extensions, and have cleared the Chrome DNS cache via chrome://net-internals/#dns.

This feels a bit scary - will end users also get 'stuck' looking up the old IP for https:// when we migrate the live site?  Will it sort itself out when the 'old' is taken offline?

Surely, if the DNS A record is pointing at a new IP, and Chrome sees and uses that, it should be doing so irregardless of protocol?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using some proxy maybe? Does the behavior persist after fully restarting the browser?

Comment: /kick-self   **A _complete_ shutdown-restart of chromium fixed it**.  Although that pretty much confirms it's a bug?   It's nearly invisible of course, because when migrating, you want identical results from both servers, and I didn't even realise for a while that I was being kicked back to the old site when I turned on forced https:// redirect on the new site.

Comment: See https://crbug.com/742187#c2 - if there's a keep-alive connection, Chrome won't re-query DNS record